# I've deleted the apache2 test page. Can I re-create it?

Tags: apache2

I've accidentally deleted the index.html apache2 test page that apache creates in /var/www/html/. Is there a way I can re-create it?

Comment: Have you checked that it isn't in the recycle bin?

Comment: I used 'sudo rm' to remove it so I didn't find it in the recycle bin.  Byte Commander's answer sorted the issue though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default Apache 2 test page is part of the `apache2-data` package that automatically gets installed with `apache2`.

You can find it in the location

```
/usr/share/apache2/default-site/index.html
```

Simply copying that file back to `/var/www/html` should do what you want to achieve.